# Inconsistent Client

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, clients

Is it common in software industry to have a client that is always inconsistent in their word?

Client almost always asks us to change business rules in our app that are not inside Functional Specification (not signed though) and consider them as bugs.

After we done some changes from A to B, this client will ask again to change from B to A, or even worse, from A to B, B to C, then C to A again.

**Note**:

This does not happen only once, but hundreds in months.

Comment: Some times they think they need to change stuff just so they are participating. I say listen let's get the whole thing working and tested per the specification.  Then you can list any changes and I will provide a quote.    Not a valid question in my opinion.  Voting to close.

Comment: Chances are, they didn't know their requirements when the functional specification was written - or couldn't understand how to express their business rules into such a document. And yes, this happens all the time.

Comment: Did you check this topic on programmers stackexchange? Search for 'changing requirements'.

Comment: what would you like to happen? if i give you a magic wand, what results you will deem positive? No changes? or better communication of changes?or better process of changes? Right now it is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the answer is "no" - because most people wouldn't work to a specification that hasn't been signed off by the customer.

You should be getting the customer to sign off the specification as part of the contract negotiation.  After that, any specification changes are chargeable extras.

Comment: Nice in theory, excellent way to ensure no further business from that customer in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the client simply doesn't know how to get what they need, and it becomes a real mess.

A real business situation I dealt with is a client sending in data in various date formats (US based, MMM-DD-YYYY, MMMM-DD-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY, MM-DD-YY, M-D-YYYY, M-D-YY).  It changes every, single, day, and causes production error every time.  They tried changing the specifications to deal with what they think they can stick with, but they just couldn't remember their own chosen format.

What I did was make a system that handled every US format available in Excel (that's the source of the problem).  Took about 4 hours to code, but I made it, and no production errors since.  The client would have never had the balls to ask us to support 6 date formats, and we probably wouldn't think it would only take me 4 hours to complete.

Comment: It could also be the client doesn't understand the impact of changes between systems or between users. Ex user A might input it as MM-DD-YY but user B might like reading it as MMM-DD-YY but doesn't know or understand the impact of changes required. You as a developer should know the impact.

Comment: took me a while to realize that MMM = {Jan, Feb, Mar...} and not some weird hex code month

Answer (score 0):

I'm ashamed to admit that I've done that (From A to B to C to A) many times when I was on the client side. The reason, more than stupidity or craziness, is that often on the client side it's only when they see the application live that they can comment. Also, the client often doesn't know how much time it takes to integrate the changes he/she requires. It's good to explain him/her the consequences of the changes he/she requests and to charge for them when they are requesting more than 10 minutes work, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's common enough, but only when both sides don't know what they're doing.

Clients are clients, you get all sorts. But the business is making the biggest mistake by not having a clear cut plan to be stuck with agreed and signed off, with everything else as extra billable costs.

With that in place, clients think a bit harder before they make changes, because it costs them money.

If they're willing to pay then it makes no difference, they can make as many silly changes as they want, it's all revenue.